# How to update one component from another component in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have web app where interface is based on vue.js 2.0.

I have component which displays input based on select2 plugin.

By default it shows selected options, but when user clicks on it, I show select2 to allow user modify options.

Code looks like this:

```
<template>
<div @click="toggleEdit">
    <span v-show="isEnabled">
        <select
            class="form-control"
            :name="name"
            :multiple="multiple"
        >
            <option v-for="opt in options" :value="opt.id"> {{ opt.text }} </option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span v-show="!isEnabled">
        <div v-if="selectedOptions.length === 0">
            {{ emptyText }}
        </div>
        <div v-for="opt in selectedOptions">
            {{ opt }}
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        options: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            default: function() {
                return []
            }
        },
        name: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        multiple: {
            required: false,
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        emptyText: {
            required: false,
            type: String,
            default: ""
        },
        sourceUrl: {
            required: false,
            type: String,
            default: ""
        },
        enabled: {
            required: false,
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            isEnabled: this.enabled
        }
    },

    watch: {
        options: {
            handler: function() {
                console.log(arguments)
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },

    mounted: function() {
        this.select = $(this.$el).find("select");
        this.select.select2();
        var that = this;
        this.select.on("change", function(e) {
            var indexMap = {};
            for(var i = 0; i < that.options.length; i++) {
                that.options[i].selected = false;
                indexMap[that.options[i].id] = i;
            }
            var selected = that.select.select2('val');
            if(typeof selected === "string") {
                selected = [selected];
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
                var index = indexMap[selected[i]];
                console.log(index)
                console.log(selected[i])
                if(index !== undefined) {
                    var option = that.options[index];
                    option.selected = true;
                    that.$set(that.options, index, option);
                }
            }
        })
        this.select.on("select2:open", function() {
            that.isEnabled = true;
        });
        this.select.on("select2:close", function() {
            that.isEnabled = false;
        });
    },
    methods: {
        toggleEdit() {
            if(this.isEnabled) return; // to pass select2 clicks
            this.isEnabled = !this.isEnabled;
            var that = this;
            this.$nextTick(function() {
                that.select.select2("open");
            });
        }
    },
    computed: {
        selectedOptions: function() {
            console.log(this.options)
            return this.options.filter(function(option) {
                console.log(option.selected);
                if(option.selected === true) return true;
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: I want to show multiple different `selects` using this component. Name attribute can be one of the following: `model1[field1]`, `model1[field2]`, ..., `model40[field1]`, ..., `model99[field15]`, where every modelN corresponds to tables in databases with it's respective fields.

When user changes options, ajax request must be sent to server, which returns json-object like this

```
{
   "errorText": null or "text with error",
   "disableFields": ["model3[field4]", "model24[field15]"]
}
```

I want to parse "disableFields" array and to disable from `this` component  `another` component.

One way to accomplish this (pseudo code):

```
foreach field in disableField:
    $(document).trigger("disableField" + field);
```

And in `mounted` method of `this` component

```
var self = this;
$(document).on("disableField" + this.name, function() {
    self.isEnabled = false
})
```

Is there a better way to do this without parent component?

Comment: for future, try to make it shorter. Your question is good quality but much too long...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is not allowed to communicate to another component directly. You can use a parent component to communicate between the components or [some kind of event bus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication).

```
var bus = new Vue();
```

Component A emits an event while component B may catch it and vice versa.

```
// component A
bus.$emit('cool_event_name', interesting_data)

// component B
bus.$on('cool_event_name', function(interesting_data) {
   console.log(interesting_data)
})
```

Another solution might be to use `$root` which can be accessed from all sub-components of a Vue instance. This economizes on the definition a global bus (like above). Note that this method is [not recommended](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html) as a general approach and acts more as a solution to certain edge cases.

```
// component A
this.$root.$emit('cool_event_name', interesting_data)

// component B
this.$root.$on('cool_event_name', function(interesting_data) {
   console.log(interesting_data)
})
```

Answer (score 32):

You can use `this.$root` without global variable:

```
// component A emits an event
export default {
  name: 'A',
  methods: {
    buttonClicked: function () {
      this.$root.$emit('myEvent', 'new message!');
    }
  }

// component B catch your event
export default {
  name: 'B',
  data () {
    return {
        message: 'Old message!'
    }
  },
  mounted: function () { 
    this.$root.$on('myEvent', (text) => { // here you need to use the arrow function
     this.message = text;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: This comment helped me solve a situation I had using $on. I wanted to fade all other v-for items except the one I had just clicked/emited an event, appreciate it.

Comment: Would this better be solved using Vuex state store or not?

Comment: I have try this but It's given error TypeError: this.$root.$on is not a function.

According to this RFC in Vue.js 3 they removed $on, $once and $off instance methods. here is the more info 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63622303/vue-js-3-this-root-on-is-not-a-function

Answer (score -1):

It is not easy to really get what you want to achieve as your post is too long and there is too many things there but I will try. If something will be missing, just comment and I will try to edit to help you better.

**DISABLED FIELDS**

I would suggest having this array in your `data` of parent component (e.g. component with whole form/page) and then pass it to your fields like `<component-instance :disabled='disabled.componentId'>` Please pay attention to `:disabled` . It is data binding which will keep this synced one-way with your parent data (it means that every change in your parent `disabled.componentId` will be reflected in your child component)

**Parsing 'Disabled' JSON**

It is quite straight forward in my opinion as you just have to assign returned fields to your `data: { disabled }` but if you can't figure it out-let us know.

** Other ways of communication between components **

If you want to update PARENT from CHILD component, you have to use EVENTS using either Vue events bus or events' handlers.
On child component you can use `<child-component @click='yourParentMethod()'>` if it is not required to pass special data from child component or create custom event emiters in child components like:

```
// child component
methods: {
someMethod() => {
this.emit('customEvent', someData)
}
}

//parent component
<child-component @customEvent='customEventHandler(dataFromChild)'>
```

Hope it helps.