# Vue.js 3 this.$root.$on is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a component which triggers `this.$root.$emit('some-root-event')` like

```
clickHandler: function() {
    this.$root.$emit("some-root-event", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    console.log('About $root.$emit')
}
```

Another component inside should catch this event but throws me an error:

> **this.$root.$on is not a function**

The code of the second component looks like

```
mounted() {
    this.$root.$on("some-root-event", (data) => {
        console.log("About listener catch $root some-root-event"); console.log(data)
    })
}
```

Can somebody help me please to understand where is the problem?

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57869399/8172857)

Comment: And why this does not work?

Comment: i don't know, i faced the same issue before and to avoid i use the event bus to emit events between components

Comment: Hello again, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471824/vue-3-event-bus/64019074?r=SearchResults&s=9|21.7970#64019074) for future needs

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [this RFC](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0020-events-api-change.md) in Vue.js 3 they removed `$on`, `$once` and `$off` instance methods :

**Their motivation** :

> Vue 1.x implemented the component event system similar to that of AngularJS, with `$dispatch` and `$broadcast` where components in a tree can communicate by sending events up and down the tree.
> In Vue 2, we removed `$dispatch` and `$broadcast` in favor of a more state-driven data flow (props down, events up).
> With Vue 2's API, `$emit` can be used to trigger event handlers declaratively attached by a parent component (in templates or render functions), but can also be used to trigger handlers attached imperatively via the event emitter API ($on, `$off` and `$once`). This is in fact an overload: the full event emitter API isn't a part of the typical inter-component data-flow. They are rarely used, and there are really no strong reason for them to be exposed via component instances. This RFC therefore proposes to remove the `$on`, `$off` and `$once` instance methods

Comment: Thank you, could you explain what should be the alternative of `this.$root.$on` / `this.$root.$off` for those who are migrating from Vue2 to Vue3 ?

Comment: You can find the migration strategy here: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#_2-x-syntax

Comment: @snoobdogg please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471824/vue-js-3-event-bus/64019074#64019074