# Creating Vue 3 Component Instances Programmatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following code in **Vue 2**

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue'

let ComponentClass, instance
let propsData = {}

ComponentClass = Vue.extend(component)
instance = new ComponentClass({ propsData })

instance.$mount()
document.body.appendChild(instance.$el)

console.log(
    instance.$on,
    instance.$once,
    instance.$mount
)
```

I need to **create** this **instance** in **Vue 3**

Does anyone know the equivalent in **Vue 3**?

**OBS**: I need the instance, $on and $once

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63622303/8172857

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim thanks for the link, but it doesn't show how to instantiate in Vue 3

Comment: did you fix this problem? @FabioNogueira